Python output GeoTIFF in arcseconds
I have been utilizing code that looks like the following to output GeoTIFFs for some time (rudimentary, but gets the job done):
def output_geotiff(data, outfile):

    # Get our dimensions
    cols = data.shape[1]
    rows = data.shape[0]

    driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')
    outRaster = driver.Create(outfile, cols, rows, 1, gdal.GDT_Float32)
    outRaster.SetGeoTransform((minlon, 0.01, 0, minlats, 0, 0.01))
    outband = outRaster.GetRasterBand(1)
    outband.WriteArray(data)
    outRasterSRS = osr.SpatialReference()
    outRasterSRS.ImportFromEPSG(4326)
    outRaster.SetProjection(outRasterSRS.ExportToWkt())
    outband.FlushCache()

Where the function would output a GeoTIFF with EPSG:4326 at an equal lat/lon spacing of 0.01 degrees.
However, I now have a 2D grid that has dimensions of 30-arcseconds per point. I change the EPSG from 4326 to 1043, and then the values of 0.01 to 30. However, when I run this I get an error such that:
ERROR 1: PROJ: proj_create_from_database: crs not found

Is it not possible to output a GeoTIFF in arcseconds - does a conversion need to be done of sorts?

1043 is not a coordinate reference system (CRS) - EPSG.org (authoritative), EPSG.io.
Not all EPSG codes are CRSs, they can also identify units, datums, transformations and various other types.
There are 3600 arc seconds in a degree, so as your data is 30 arcsec resolution, just specify the resolution as 0.083333 (30/3600) and leave CRS as 4326.
